# Go 1.9 gives runtime error on Windows 10

Tags: go

I installed Go 1.9 on Windows 10 and when I ran a class 'Hello World' program it gave me the following error.

```
# runtime
C:\Go\src\runtime\mstkbar.go:151:10: debug.gcstackbarrieroff undefined (type struct { allocfreetrace int32; cgocheck int32; efence int32; gccheckmark int32; gcpacertrace int32; gcshrinkstackoff int32; gcrescanstacks int32; gcstoptheworld int32; gctrace int32; invalidptr int32; sbrk int32; scavenge int32; scheddetail int32; schedtrace int32 } has no field or method gcstackbarrieroff)
C:\Go\src\runtime\mstkbar.go:162:24: division by zero
C:\Go\src\runtime\mstkbar.go:162:43: invalid expression unsafe.Sizeof(composite literal)
C:\Go\src\runtime\mstkbar.go:162:44: undefined: stkbar
C:\Go\src\runtime\mstkbar.go:212:4: gp.stkbar undefined (type *g has no field or method stkbar)
C:\Go\src\runtime\mstkbar.go:213:15: gp.stkbar undefined (type *g has no field or method stkbar)
C:\Go\src\runtime\mstkbar.go:216:23: undefined: stackBarrierPC
C:\Go\src\runtime\mstkbar.go:226:28: gp.stkbarPos undefined (type *g has no field or method stkbarPos)
C:\Go\src\runtime\mstkbar.go:227:19: gp.stkbarPos undefined (type *g has no field or method stkbarPos)
C:\Go\src\runtime\mstkbar.go:248:41: undefined: stkbar
C:\Go\src\runtime\mstkbar.go:227:19: too many errors
```

When I ran `go env`, it gave me the following output,

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\indu\go
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
```

Comment: Did you uninstall go 1.8 first?  Possible that maybe you have mixed versions in C:\Go?

Comment: I reset the windows and after that installed, let me remove the folder and re-install.

Comment: Removing folder and re-installing worked. Thank You so much @DavidBudworth! I didn't think the solution will be that simple :), because the error message seemed very dirty.

Comment: yep, when you see crazy stuff happening in the runtime itself, it's highly likely that your files are "corrupt" in some way.   In this case, the go team probably removed some files, so you had some 1.8 remnants + 1.9, and go compiles all files in a package together.

Comment: So it's the recommended way to remove the Go root folder and reinstall, right?
I didn't think this problem will solve so easily.

Comment: yes, delete original folder and then install.  Or you could install go in a folder with the version in it, like `C:\Go\1.9`, but then you have to update your path and stuff.  That's only useful if you need to keep multiple versions around, which most people do not.

Comment: I'm assuming you do not keep your source code in that directory too, but have GOPATH somewhere else?   You should make sure you don't mix your code with the runtime's code, which will make delete / install easier as you won't accidentally delete your personal stuff.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with this: https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#goroot

Comment: @DavidBudworth Yes I keep my code at 'user/go' and Go installs at c:/Go.

majidarif: No, actually I had old (1.8) installation's files remaining.

Answer (score 3):

Really weird issues in the runtime with no obvious cause are often caused by not uninstalling a pervious version before installing the new one.

Sadly [the Go installation instructions](https://golang.org/doc/install) make no mention of the issue.

In general you should move or delete your old Go install, and install the new version from scratch.

If you are building from source (the way I do) it is best to move the old version to a diferent directory, and then configure a temporary environment so you can use the old version to build the new one. If installing from the official binaries just deleting the old version is simplest.

Regardless of how you are installing you should never place your own code in the same tree as the runtime code, so just deleting the old runtime and reinstalling/rebuilding should always be possible.